# Angular momentum operator in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, many-body, second-quantization

I wanted to know what the angular momentum operator in the second quantization would look like in terms of the annihilation and creation operators.

Comment: Have you tried simply computing them? In SR QFT it is standard to talk about the M matrix operator that enacts rotations, along with boosts. In cond mat QFT it is common to use single-particle expansions, and if you pick the LCAO ones, the angular momentum eigenstates are chosen. Do note that the spin part will continue to be annoying, though.

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually, it is nothing surprising. The second quantized form of a general first quantized one-body operator $\hat{A}$ is
$$
{\cal{A}}=\sum_{p,q}\langle \phi_p|\hat{A}|\phi_q\rangle a_p^{\dagger}a_q
\ ,
$$
where $\{\phi_p\}$ is an (at this point) arbitrary orthonormal basis of one-particle states. Then similarly, we can write the $k$-th component of a general angular momentum operator ($k=1,2,3$) as
$$
{\cal{J}}_k=\sum_{p,q}\langle \phi_p|\hat{J}_k|\phi_q\rangle a_p^{\dagger}a_q \ .
$$
It is worth discussing how to bring ${\cal{J}}^2={\cal{J}}_k{\cal{J}}_k$ into a more practical form. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{J}}^2&={\cal{J}}_1{\cal{J}}_1+{\cal{J}}_2{\cal{J}}_2+{\cal{J}}_3{\cal{J}}_3 \\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\left({\cal{J}}_+{\cal{J}}_-+{\cal{J}}_-{\cal{J}}_+\right)+{\cal{J}}_3{\cal{J}}_3 \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where we introduced
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{J}}_\pm&={\cal{J}}_1\pm i{\cal{J}}_2 \\
             &=\sum_{p,q}\langle \phi_p|\hat{J}_\pm|\phi_q\rangle a_p^{\dagger}a_q \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
in analogy with the first quantized ladder operators ${\hat{J}}_\pm={\hat{J}}_1\pm i{\hat{J}}_2$. Second quantization preserves the algebra of operators, so we can anticipate the commutation relation $[{\cal{J}}_-,{\cal{J}}_+]=-2\hbar{\cal{J}}_3$, but it might be instructive to check this on the level of creation-annihilation operators:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left[{\cal{J}}_-,{\cal{J}}_+\right]
&=
\sum_{p,q,r,s}\langle \phi_p|\hat{J}_-|\phi_q\rangle
\langle \phi_r|\hat{J}_+|\phi_s\rangle
\left[a_p^\dagger a_q,a_r^\dagger a_s\right] \\
&=
\sum_{p,q,r,s}\langle \phi_p|\hat{J}_-|\phi_q\rangle
\langle \phi_r|\hat{J}_+|\phi_s\rangle
\left(\delta_{rq}a_p^\dagger a_s-\delta_{ps}a_r^\dagger a_q\right) \\
&=
\sum_{p,q}\langle \phi_p|\left[\hat{J}_-,\hat{J}_+\right]|\phi_q\rangle a_p^\dagger a_q \\
&=
-2\hbar
\sum_{p,q}\langle \phi_p|\hat{J}_3|\phi_q\rangle a_p^\dagger a_q \\
&=
-2\hbar{\cal{J}}_3 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The commutator of the creation-annihilation operators holds for both bosons and fermions, as expected; we also used the completeness of the one-particle basis:
$$
\hat{I}=\sum_p|\phi_p\rangle\langle\phi_p| \ .
$$
Putting everything together, we find the practical forms
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{J}}^2
   &={\cal{J}}_+{\cal{J}}_-+{\cal{J}}_3{\cal{J}}_3-\hbar{\cal{J}}_3 \\
   &={\cal{J}}_-{\cal{J}}_++{\cal{J}}_3{\cal{J}}_3+\hbar{\cal{J}}_3
 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Up to this point, nothing was assumed about our one-particle basis, except for orthonormality. Some further simplification can be achieved, if the basis is chosen conveniently. For example, the spin operator ($\cal{J}_k=\cal{S}_k$) for a system of spin $1/2$ particles has a very simple representation: separating the general spin-orbital index of the one-particle functions as $p=P\sigma$ ($P$ and $\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow$ labeling the spatial and spin degrees of freedom, respectively), we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{S}}_3&=\sum_{P,Q}\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}\langle \phi_{P\sigma}|\hat{S}_3|\phi_{Q\sigma'}\rangle a_{P\sigma}^{\dagger}a_{Q\sigma'} \\
&=
\sum_{P,Q}\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}\frac{\hbar}{2}\delta_{PQ}\delta_{\sigma\sigma'}\left(\delta_{\sigma\uparrow}-\delta_{\sigma\downarrow}\right) a_{P\sigma}^{\dagger}a_{Q\sigma'} \\
&=
\frac{\hbar}{2}\sum_{P}\left(a_{P\uparrow}^{\dagger}a_{P\uparrow}-a_{P\downarrow}^{\dagger}a_{P\downarrow}\right) \\
&=
\frac{\hbar}{2}\left({\cal{N}}_\uparrow-{\cal{N}}_\downarrow\right) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Operator ${\cal{S}}_3$ measures the number difference of spin up and spin down particles, as expected. We similarly find
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{S}}_+=\hbar\sum_{P} a_{P\uparrow}^{\dagger}a_{P\downarrow} \ \ , \ \
{\cal{S}}_-=\hbar\sum_{P} a_{P\downarrow}^{\dagger}a_{P\uparrow} \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
in accordance with their interpretation as ladder operators.
We used
$$
\langle\phi_{P\sigma}|\hat{S}_+|\phi_{Q\sigma'}\rangle=
\hbar\delta_{PQ}\delta_{\sigma\uparrow}\delta_{\sigma'\downarrow} \ ,
$$
and analogous relations. One can obtain similar but more complicated expressions for general angular momenta on the appropriate eigenbases.
For example, in atomic calculations, the appropriate basis for orbital angular momentum (${\cal{J}}_k={\cal{L}}_k$) could be a set of angular momentum eigenfunctions, with (spatial) quantum numbers $P=\kappa lm$ ($l$ and $m=-l,...,+l$ being the usual angular quantum numbers, $\kappa$ being some further quantum number). Then we have
$$
  {\cal{L}}_3=\hbar\sum_{\kappa}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{'}\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}
  m\sum_{\sigma}
  \hat{a}_{\kappa lm\sigma}^{\dagger}
  \hat{a}_{\kappa l m\sigma}^{{\color{white}\dagger}} \ ,
$$
$$
  {\cal{L}}_\pm=\hbar\sum_{\kappa}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{'}\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}
  \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m\mp1)}\sum_{\sigma}
  \hat{a}_{\kappa lm\sigma}^{\dagger}
  \hat{a}_{\kappa l m\mp1\sigma}^{{\color{white}\dagger}} \ ,
$$
where the prime denotes possible restrictions on the range of $l$ imposed by $\kappa$ (for example, $\kappa=n=1,2,...$ and $l=0,...,n-1$ for the discrete part of the spectrum if hydrogenic orbitals are used).